# Active Record, Code Igniter, join table 'users' twice

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, query-builder, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to achieve something I did a few years ago in Ruby on Rails.
Now I'm using CodeIgniter 3.0.0.
Below an overview of what I want to achieve:

#### Tables:

```
Table: users               Table: articles
_________________          _______________________________________
| id | name     |          | id | description | buyer | applicant |
|  1 | John D.  |          |  1 | PC Mouse    |     1 |         2 |
|  2 | Anita F. |
```

#### I want to achieve this: (or something alike)

```
        Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [description] => 'PC Mouse'
            [buyer] => stdClass Object
                (
                     [id] => 1
                     [name] => 'John D.'
                )
            [applicant] => stdClass Object
                (
                     [id] => 2
                     [name] => 'Anita F.'
                )
        )
)
```

#### So I can call:

```
echo $article->description;       //=> PC Mouse
echo $article->buyer->name;       //=> John D.
echo $article->applicant->name;   //=> Anita F.
```

---

#### I've tried (without luck):

```
$this->db->from('articles');
$this->db->join('users', 'articles.buyer = users.id');
$this->db->join('users'. 'articles.applicant = users.id');
$objects = $this->db->get()->result_object();

//=> Throws:
Error 1066:
Not unique table/alias: 'users'
```

```
$this->db->from('articles');
$this->db->join('users', 'articles.buyer = users.id');
$objects = $this->db->get()->result_object();

//=> returns an extra column 'name' with the value 'John D.'
        Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [description] => 'PC Mouse'
            [buyer] => 1
            [applicant] => 2
            [name] => 'John D.'
         )
)
```

I read a lot about `group_by`, but I can't get it to work.
Can you help me figure this out?
Could this even be a solution or is it even possible ?!

#### Side-info

This is a stripped down example of what I need.
I have a lot more joins to make.

This is what I should have eventually:

```
purchases has many articles        (articles.purchasesID)
articles  has one  status          (statusID)
articles  has one  brand           (brandID)
purchases has one  buyer           (usersID)
purchases has one  applicant       (usersID)
purchases has one  status          (statusID)
purchases has one  delivered_to    (usersID)
purchases has one  suppliers       (suppliersID)
purchases has one  concerns        (concernsID

// When I want to echo the status of an article:
// Status has an 'id' and 'name' so:
echo $purchase->article[0]->status->name  //=> 'Processing'

// or when I want to know who the product is delivered to:
echo $purchase->delivered_to->name  //=> 'Carsten'
```

Hope you can help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your multiple joins are not working is because you have to give them **aliases** ([source](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)). Once you have your results, you need to iterate through them so that you can build your object the way you want them to.

- **Step 1:** build your query

  ```
  $this->db->select('
      a.*,
      bu.name as buyer_name,
      au.name as applicant_name
  ');
  $this->db->from('articles a');
  $this->db->join('users bu', 'a.buyer = bu.id', 'left');
  $this->db->join('users au', 'a.applicant = au.id', 'left');
  $results = $this->db->get()->result();
  ```
- **Step 2:** iterate through your results to build your desired object

  ```
  foreach ($results as $res) {
      $buyer_obj = new stdClass();
      $buyer_obj->id = $res->buyer;
      $buyer_obj->name = $res->buyer_name;
      $res->buyer = $buyer_obj;
      unset($res->buyer_name);

      $applicant_obj = new stdClass();
      $applicant_obj->id = $res->applicant;
      $applicant_obj->name = $res->applicant_name;
      $res->applicant = $applicant_obj;
      unset($res->applicant_name);
  }
  ```
- **Step 3:** check your results

  ```
  var_dump($results);
  ```

Hope this helps :)